# Find all links of a particular type.

Tags: desire2learn, valence

We have an unknown number of instructors who have added videos from [mix.microsoft.com](https://mix.office.com/en-us/Home) to their courses. Now mix.microsoft.com is being retired and all of those links will be broken.

Is there a way that I can search for all of those links, wherever they might be? In content, in announcements?

Open to internal tools or valence or whatever.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You could, in theory, look for links in course content. In cases where someone added such a video URL as a [link type content topic (topic type 3)](http://docs.valence.desire2learn.com/res/content.html#Content.ContentObject), you can look for the `Url` property being one that matches to the domain you're looking for (mix.microsoft.com). In cases where someone has added a [file type content topic (topic type 1)](http://docs.valence.desire2learn.com/res/content.html#Content.ContentObject), things get trickier -- you can use the [API call to retrieve the underlying file](http://docs.valence.desire2learn.com/res/content.html#get--d2l-api-le-(version)-(orgUnitId)-content-topics-(topicId)-file) for such a topic type, and then parse through the file data you get back looking for matching links; however, depending on what kind of data format that file-type content topic is in, this may be difficult or not feasible. (For file-type topic content that's authored using Brightspace's own content editing tool, you'll get back an HTML document within which you can search for links.)

Note, also, that you may be able to update the links in link-type content topics, but you can't update the contents of a file-type content topic (you have to essentially create new ones and then delete the old ones).

For links embedded in places other than course content in the LMS, things may likely become more challenging, depending upon the domain of things you're looking at.